# VBA code to fill Word fields from Access only fires every other time

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I'm relatively new to Access, but I've been trying to put a package together this week to issue letters to our employees.

The flow is as follows:
Form filled on Access > Data saved to Table > Relevant fields merged into Word Template

I seem to be having some issues with the VBA code which transposes the data to Word. I found this code online and whilst it does work, it only works every OTHER time. I've tried cutting bits out and so far not been successful. The way it **consistently** works on every other occasion seems somewhat bizarre. I've found lots of reference to this phenomenon online but they typically relate to Excel and I haven't found a solution that works as yet. Code included below for reference.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this.

Joe

```
Private Sub Command280_Click()

'Print customer slip for current customer.
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear
'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.
Set appWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("filepath-to-document.docx", , True)
With doc
.FormFields("txtFirstName").Result = Me![First Name]
.FormFields("txtFirstName2").Result = Me![First Name]
.FormFields("txtLastName").Result = Me![Last Name]
.FormFields("txtReasonforReward").Result = Me![Reason for Reward]
.FormFields("txtCompanyValue").Result = Me![Company Value]
.FormFields("txtRequestingManager").Result = Me![Requesting Manager]
.FormFields("txtLocation").Result = Me![Location]
.Visible = True
.Activate
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

In response to some comments, I have amended my code as follows, this code does however not have any error management and causes documents to open in Web view(?):

```
Private Sub Command280_Click()
Dim objWord As Object
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Add("FilePath.docx", , True)
With doc
.FormFields("txtFirstName").Result = Me![First Name]
.FormFields("txtFirstName2").Result = Me![First Name]
.FormFields("txtLastName").Result = Me![Last Name]
.FormFields("txtReasonforReward").Result = Me![Reason for Reward]
.FormFields("txtCompanyValue").Result = Me![Company Value]
.FormFields("txtRequestingManager").Result = Me![Requesting Manager]
.FormFields("txtLocation").Result = Me![Location]
.Visible = True
.Activate
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by reinitializing the error handler after you've instantiated the Word application object (`On Error GoTo 0` before that `Set doc = ...`. You're likely getting some error you're not seeing because you're suppressing all errors

Comment: The code does not *close* the document, but does open it each time. This could certainly cause problems. It would make more sense, I suspect, to use `Documents.Add` rather than `Documents.Open` to always crete a new *copy* of the document.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I have tweaked my code (despite not really having a clue) and have taken out most of the error suppression. Please advise as to whether this appears correct? (see edited question)

Also, documents now open into word as "Document X" (which is fine) but open in the Web view as opposed to Print. Can I force this with the VBA?